# Wrapping typedef struct in Boost Python module

Tags: c++, boost, struct, typedef, boost-python

I have a typedef defined in a header as such below:

```
typedef struct data
{
    std::string id;
    std::string status;

} data_set;
```

I want to be able to wrap this in a Boost Python Module to make it available since it's passed into other methods. Would this be wrapped as a class in boost? or is there a specific way to wrap typedefs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the typedef here. Simply

```
struct data_set
{
    std::string id;
    std::string status;

};
```

is [mostly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c) equivalent. That being said, now you can just treat it as a class with the Boost Python Module.